# Preventing Devise/ActionMailer from sending confirmation email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

I am using Devise with ActionMailer. I would like to allow users to create an account without email if they use Twitter. But I still need devise:confirmable if they choose to add email later on.

However, Devise automatically send confirmation email when an user create a new account, even if user does not supply it. Therefore, I got error when deploy my Rails app to Heroku:

```
ArgumentError (At least one recipient (To, Cc or Bcc) is required to send a message):
```

How can I prevent Devise or ActionMailer from sending confirmation email when there's no email address?

Thank you.

Comment: Does [this wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How%20To:%20Email-only%20sign-up) help? You could try tweaking the implementation to suit your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise has a `skip_confirmation!` method that should allow you to accomplish this, check out the [confirmable.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L116)